# What is the best way to remove all elements in a pandas dataframe where a value in one columns exists more than once in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame consisting of several trees. I want to remove all the rows where the `RootNode` is present more than once in the `ToNode` column. However, a node in `ToNode` can be present more than once, if it's not a root node.

Here is an example of the df.

```
ToNode | FromNode | Root
  A        None      A  
  B         A        A
  C        None      C 
  A         C        C  
  B         A        C
```

Here I would want to remove all rows where `Root == A` so that the resulting df is

```
ToNode | FromNode | Root  
  C        None      C 
  A         C        C  
  B         A        C
```

One approach (which is very slow) to achieve this is the following:

```
root_list = list(df['Root'].unique())
for node in root_list:
  if len(df[df['ToNode'] == node]) > 1:
    df = df[df['Root'] != node]
```

I would imagine that there is a much faster way, perhaps using `groupby()` and `transform()` and/or `map` / `apply`.

Anyone have any tips on how to make this faster?

Comment: _Here I would want to remove all rows where Root == A so that the resulting df is_  try `df = df.loc[df.loc[:, 'Root'] != 'A', :]`

Comment: I do not just want to remove the Root "A", it's an example. I can have 1000 different `Root` values which I want to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with boolean indexing. `~` here is logical `NOT`:

```
nodes_to_remove = df['ToNode'].value_counts()[lambda x: x > 1].index
#print(nodes_to_remove) Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')

df[~df['Root'].isin(nodes_to_remove)]
```

[out]

```
  ToNode FromNode Root
2      C     None    C
3      A        C    C
4      B        A    C
```

Answer (score 1):

first find all `ToNode` which has `>1` occurance using groupby and filter `df` on `Root`

```py
df2 = df.groupby(['ToNode'], as_index=False).count()
df[~df['Root'].isin(df2[df2['Root'] > 1]['ToNode'].unique())]
```

which gives you the following result.

```
    ToNode  FromNode    Root
2   C   None    C
3   A   C   C
4   B   A   C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following.

- use `value_counts` to get counts
- get the index where the count >= 2 satifies
- drop those rows.

```py
>>> df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=1)[['A']] >= 2
       A
0   True
1   True
2  False
3  False
4  False

>>> mask = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=1)[['A']] >= 2
>>> mask[mask.A].index
Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')

>>> idx = mask[mask.A].index
>>> df.drop(idx)
  ToNode FromNode Root
2      C     None    C
3      A        C    C
4      B        A    C
```